# How to Parse HTML in Powershell 5 with -UseBasicParsing

Tags: powershell, html-parsing, powershell-5.0

Often `Invoke-WebRequest` is preferable in usage with the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter, if not using `Invoke-RestMethod` command for both performance and network savings.

But the results from these don't have the good ol' `PARSEHTML` method.

How can we parse html using the stated command setups?

1. `Invoke-Webrequest $site -UseBasicParsing`
2. `Invoke-RestMethod $site`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scenario can be solved by creating a new HTML object and writing to its **IHTMLDocument2** section

**NOTE: THIS IS ONLY VALID IN WINDOWS POWERSHELL 5.0 and 5.1**

You can deal with the listed scenarios as follows:

1. For **Invoke-Webrequest $site -UseBasicParsing**

   `$html = new-object -ComObject "HTMLFile; $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($site.rawcontent)`
2. For **Invoke-RestMethod $site**

   `$html = new-object -ComObject "HTMLFile; $html.IHTMLDocument2_write($site)`

Now you can parse like normal
for example getting an element by id

`$button = $html.getElementById('button')`

Comment: how do you do this in powershell 7.1?